# How do I get access to BufferedInputStream pos and markpos variables?

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I have a set of self deserializing classes that take data from a socket. The serialized data format provides length information in a header preceeding the payload. In case the payload is not deseriablizable I would like to skip the entire block using the length information in the aforementioned header.
However, in order to do so I would need to know how much data has already been read from the socket. I thought that `BufferedInputStream` would allow me to do that using `mark()` before deserialization of the payload starts and then use pos and markpos to determine the amount of data read but realized that those two variables or protected.

Is there a better way to get access to this information other than sub-classing `BufferedInputStream`?

Answer (score 1):

You can `mark()` BIS before deserialisation, and then call `reset()`.

There are public.

Then you can skip any number of bytes, by `skip` method.

[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#method_summary)